# Removing the link from a Visualforce lookup field output

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I'm using a VF page to incorporate data from a Contract to output onto a PDF document.

When I tried to print the value of a lookup field straight up (e.g. {!contract.Outside_Broker_Name__c}), it would print the id of the object instead, so I had to do this:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!contract.Outside_Broker_Name__c}" />
```

But what happens it that now it prints the name with the link to the object, so in the pdf it shows as a blue text with an underline in it.

How do I get rid of this link? Or perhaps a better question is, how can I directly access the parent object so that I can access its fields directly from VF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`apex:outputText`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_compref_outputText.htm) with the related object's name (`Outside_Broker_Name__r.Name`) instead.

```
<apex:outputtext value="{!contract.Outside_Broker_Name__r.Name}" />
```

If the Contract is coming from a custom Controller, Extension, or SOQL query, you'll have to query for `Outside_Broker_Name__r.Name` as well, like this:

```
[Select Id, Name, Outside_Broker_Name__c, Outside_Broker_Name__r.Name From Contract]
```

Comment: I tried outputText already, unfortunately it prints the id instead of the name.

Comment: Right, but use the relationship to get the name in the outputtext: `Outside_Broker_Name__r.Name`.

Comment: @Matt K, How would you remove the hyperlink if the field is coming from a field set and you only have the reference available?

Comment: I figured it out, it looks like you can access all the fields in the references in the field set.